# cannot find package "gopkg.in/validator.v2" error

Tags: windows, go, package

When I am trying to build my Go project in Windows by using

```
go build
```

, its giving an error,

> api.go:7:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/validator.v2" in any of:
>
> C:\Go\src\gopkg.in\validator.v2 (from $GOROOT)
>
> C:\Home\GO..\src\gopkg.in\validator.v2 (from $GOPATH)

How to add this package to my project?

When I tried to add the above package by,

```
go get gopkg.in\validator.v2
```

then its giving another error like,

> go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd package
>   gopkg.in/validator.v2: exec: "git": executable file not found in
>   %PATH%

Comment: By doing `go get`.

Comment: @Volker : Its giving another error, 

_go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package gopkg.in/validator.v2: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%_

Comment: Install git and append the executable directory to your PATH so you can use it from cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go get` uses git or hg to fetch a package, so you have to install it. For windows you can use this [link](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Comment: I have installed Git in my system. But still the error is there. Is there any path setting is required for Git?